# Python file writing error because of "/" in the file name

Tags: python, string, file, response.write

I have a code chunk like this

```
for track in (results['tracks']):
        track_id_chunk.append(track['uri'])
        print (str(z) + " - " + track['name'])
        try:
            r = requests.get(track['preview_url'], allow_redirects=True)
            open('dataset/'+genres[x]+"/"+str(track['name'])+'.mp3', 'wb').write(r.content)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print ("---------------------- Couldnt get "+artists[j]+"  -  "+track['name'] + " !!!")
            continue
        z+=1
```

It downloads 30 seconds samples of artists given externally using spotify API.

The problem is when a song has a "/" in its name ("War Pigs / Luke's Wall - 2014 Remaster" for example) the file operation looks for the directory before "/", fails to find it and throws error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "dataset/metal/War Pigs / Luke's Wall - 2014 Remaster.mp3"
```

what is the best practice workaround or solution for this problem?

Comment: Have a look at: https://pypi.org/project/pathvalidate/#sanitize-a-filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Linux you can't have slashes in your filename.
My suggestion is to replace the character with something else like '-':

```
str(track['name']).replace('/', '-')
```

Comment: `/` and `\0` are the only bytes not allowed in a Linux filename.

Comment: @EmreÜnsal I just checked the MS docs and it looks like `/` is not valid as part of a filename on Windows either. Makes sense because Windows also allows using `/` as a path separator.

Comment: Actually, Windows uses ``\`` as a path separator, but it's still true that `/` isn't permitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `slugify` function which is defined below,

### The `slugify(value)`

**Code:**

```
def slugify(value):
    """
    converts to lowercase, removes non-alpha characters,
    and converts spaces to hyphens.
    """
    value = re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '', value).strip().lower()
    value = re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-', value)
    return value
```

***Converts a string to a proper filename by:***

- Removing characters that aren’t alphanumerics, underscores, hyphens,
  or whitespace.
- Removing leading and trailing whitespace.
- Converting to lowercase.
- Replacing any whitespace or repeated dashes with single dashes.

**Usage:**

```
>>> slugify('War Pigs / Luke's Wall - 2014 Remaster')
```

**Output:**

```
war-pigs-lukes-wall-2014-remaster
```